# MSSQL same collation columns show different data

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have two databases.
I get data from first database and put it to second.
So the main problem that I have a same columns

> (collation - Latin1_General_CI_AS, data type - nvarchar, length - 90) .

but first database's column displays a specific symbols like "ā", "ī", "ē", etc. and the second databases's column turn it to "a", "i", "e".

So can you please tell me a reason why this this happens?

Comment: It doesn't. SQL Server stores what you give it, and `ā` will fit in an `NVARCHAR` regardless of collation. But if any client application or queries or stored procedures were to pass a `VARCHAR` by mistake, the `ā` gets turned into `a` as the collation doesn't support it. (Note that the collation involved in this case is the database default, not the actual collation of your destination column, although those are typically the same.)

Comment: One possibility is the code that inserts into the second databases uses literals without prefix `N` to denote Unicode (e.g. 'ā' instead of N'ā').

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you, it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sure that you prefix Unicode string literals with an N prefix. Like this.

**QUERY 1: (OLD Query's String)**

```
SELECT 'If the alternative 
 hypothesis is as  Ha:µ ≠µ0';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
If the alternative hypothesis is as Ha:µ ?µ0
```

In the above query `≠` is missing

**QUERY 2: (NEW Query's String)**

```
SELECT 'If the alternative 
 hypothesis is as  Ha:' + N'µ ≠µ0';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
If the alternative hypothesis is as Ha:µ ≠µ0
```